# Options for HTML editing in JavaFX

Tags: java, swing, tinymce, javafx-2, html-editor

I'm looking to replace an HTML editor used within a Swing based application with one based on JavaFX.

As far as I can see, there are two possible options:
1) Use the JavaFX HTML editor. 
While this is quite nice for the features it *does* have, it is still lacking several other features (e.g. insert an image, insert a table, manipulate the image or table, etc.). I am also looking to include other features such as spellcheck and the ability to support custom tags.
2) Use the JavaFX WebView component and use an embedded editor such as TinyMCE.

So what would be the best option? Has anyone enhanced the JavaFX HTML editor?
Are there any "gotchas" with going with the second option?
Is there a third option I should consider?

Comment: Are you table to ditch HTML and use a markdown editor?  This is suprisingly simple.  HTML editors are just horrid, even the good ones.  Try cut and pasting from a word doc and then attempt to get uniform styling.

Comment: I don't have the option for ditching HTML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Defining a best option is an unanswerable question as that would depend on the application at hand.

For related info see:

- [How to hide the controls of HTMLEditor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075841/how-to-hide-the-controls-of-htmleditor)
- [JavaFX HTMLEditor - Insert image function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10968000/javafx-htmleditor-insert-image-function)
- [Set a local image in JavaFX HTMLeditor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15802619/set-a-local-image-in-javafx-htmleditor)
- [HtmlEditorCustomizationSample](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/2514709)
- [Discussion on pros and cons of HtmlEditor customization](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=10301445)
- [Webview with contenteditable cannot be focused programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10685395/webview-with-contenteditable-cannot-be-focused-programmatically)
- [Embedding a 3rd party editor JavaScript based editor in WebView](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/1463485)
- [Create table in HtmlEditor](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-28926)

Comment: Thanks Jewelsea. I had already looked at most of your links before posting this including your sample code for modifying the HTML editor toolbar.
My main issue here is that I would personally prefer the JavaFX HTML editor but it is lacking several features so I'd have to implement it myself, assuming no one else has already. TinyMCE (or equiv.) already has most of the features I need but I'm worried about unforeseen "gotchas".