# Table tool in javafx HTML Editor

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I am not able to add table in HTMLEditor in javafx.
How can i add the the function or tool in htmleditor toolbar for adding tables in editor in javafx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you have to implement inserting table function.

In this question's answer, you can see some example of modifing the editor:
[Options for HTML editing in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931588/options-for-html-editing-in-javafx)

Also an example for adding custom functions to the HTMLEditor:
https://gist.github.com/dipu-bd/425a86105dbeb42ad31d

Comment: Thanks Ansaldas. Is there anyting like using CKEditor?

Comment: I think no, only the native HTMLEditor.

Comment: Thank for the help Ansaldos. can you tell how should i implement inserting table function ?