# find HTMLEditor cursor pointer for inserting image

Tags: html, javafx, html-editor

as said in topic: [JavaFX HTMLEditor - Insert image function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10968000/javafx-htmleditor-insert-image-function)
if want to insert image should add below tag to htmlText of htmlEditor

```
"<img src=\"" + getClass().getResource(PicName[i])) + "\" width=\"" + target.getImage().getWidth() + "\"height=\"" + target.getImage().getHeight()  + "\">")
```

but if want to add image in cursor position how to do it?

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this in the following way

1. Use the [ScenicView](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/) to explore the HTMLEditor
   [image: scenic view]
2. Get WebView inside HTMLEditor
3. Get WebEngine of that WebView
4. Run a JavaScript Code to Insert an image to the caret pos using WebEngine

How To Replace HTML using JS 
[Link to Original Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213376/how-to-find-cursor-position-in-a-contenteditable-div)

```
function insertHtmlAtCursor(html) {
    var range, node;
    if (window.getSelection && window.getSelection().getRangeAt) {
        range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
        node = range.createContextualFragment(html);
        range.insertNode(node);
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        document.selection.createRange().pasteHTML(html);
    }
}
```

How to Execute JS Code [Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/webview/jfxpub-webview.htm)

```
Node webNode = htmlEditor.lookup(".web-view");
if (webNode instanceof WebView) {
     WebView webView = (WebView) webNode;
     WebEngine engine = webView.getEngine();
     engine.executeScript("alert('helo')"); // add js code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

text fileds are have a linear datastructure and can have a sequential position and corresponding location in its view. 
but for html view the displayed object location on screen to location in the text mapping is a bit difficult so thats why the html editor cant determine the cursor position

im working on some other workaround to insert image at given cursor position.

try to insert a dummy text as a placeholder like ###inserImage#### then replace it with the actual image tag <img src="file:\c:\testhtmleditor\sample01.jpg" />..

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this piece of code

```
@FXML private HTMLEditor editor; 
... 
public void insertTextToCurrentFeatureCursorPosition(String text) {
    WebView webView = (WebView) editor.lookup(".web-view");
    WebPage webPage = Accessor.getPageFor(webView.getEngine());
    webPage.executeCommand("insertHTML", text); 
}
```

Where text is the HTML code which wraps the image